# Can I get rid of the "Okay. Let's get the test version XXX" with unpublished google home actions?

Tags: testing, google-home

I want to develop some google home Im using DialogFlow actions which will perform actions specific to my home.Alas given they need access to my home network its not going to be something I can publish.. Ive done some tinkering and Ive realised that when you run actions which are not published (testing) you always get the sentence 
"Okay. Let's get the test version XXX" before it runs your action..

Is there anyway around this?

Also is it still true that you can only have one action in test and it only stays live 24hrs?

thanks